# which webpack devtool is suitable for chrome apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-app, source-maps

I've migrated my **chrome-app** build process from grunt to webpack.
At first I used `source-map` as the webpack devtool.

Everything seemed to work as expected but when I compressed my build the debug was buggy - unable to inspect variables, the actual executed code wasn't perfectly aligned with chrome highlighted line...

So I've tried `cheap-module-eval-source-map` which worked **perfectly** in the web browser(chrome) but in chrome app throws an error `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".`

**So, which devtool should I use when compressing my build and running it as a chromeapp?**

*My webpack shortened config:*

```
{
  // also tried:
  // cheap-module-source-map - doesn't work at all
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map - throws an error on chrome-apps
  // source-map - buggy when using with uglify plugin
  // inline-source-map - same as source-map
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  ]
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Due to strict [Chrome apps "Content Security Policy"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy), appropriate [webpack devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) may be one of this:

- `inline-cheap-source-map` - transformed code (lines only)
- `inline-cheap-module-source-map` - original source (lines only)
- `inline-source-map` - original source

Reason is chrome apps can't:

- evaluate js from string
- load map as a separate file, so you need inlined map